# Is it possible to position the circles so that their centers would locate on one line?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Given two circles with the radius of $1$, two circles with a radius of $2$ and two coins of the radius $3$. It is allowed to put two of them so these circles would touch each other.. Then the circles are constructed one by one,the added circle must touch at least two of the other circles on the plane. Circles may not overlap. Is it possible to position the circles so that the centers **of three any coins** would locate on one line?

Comment: If the circles may overlap, yes, for example r1 and r2 are inside r3. Then place another r1 inside r2 so it touches the first r1. Then place an r2 at one and an r3 at the other end. Each touches *exactly* 2 others.

Comment: Forgot to mention it in the problem, sorry. It is not allowed to overlap circles.

Comment: That makes the question rather silly. If the first two circles must touch, it is impossible to place another on the same line so it touches them both.

Comment: Is it allowed for one circle to be inside another?

Comment: That was my answer.

Comment: That is another mistake in the problem. Verified everything, it should be correct now. Apologies once again.

Comment: What does "the centers of three any coins" mean? If it means "any three coins" that too is impossible unless all coins are colinear.

Comment: We choose any three coins and see if that is correct. Not for EVERY three coins.

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution valid? I don't think there is a solution unless some circles are included in others[image]